# Custom Top Navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-masterpage, design-manager, top-navigation

I'm creating a custom master page and I want to create a new top navigation similar to this [page](https://glenview.il.us/Pages/Default.aspx). I only know how to add it using content editor but I don't want the menus to appear on any dialog boxes as well (i.e. **Add a Page** from the **GEAR** icon). 
[image]

I added the html snippet for **Top Navigation** from Design Manager and read through this [page](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/11/sharepoint-2013-top-navigation-bar-branding-css.html) and I can't figure out how to customize the links. I dont want it to automatically extract the links from the **Pages** library.

In DevTools, it seems it possible to remove it but I can't figure out how to code it properly in css targeting a class inside another class:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I just have to list every id and class. Below code seems to work on dialog box for the 'add a page' and any list dialog box.

```
    .ms-dialog .ms-backgroundImage #aspnetForm #s4-workspace #custTopNavigation .topnavbar{
    display: none;
}
```

My master template has background color and the list dialog box also inherited the background color in its ribbon so I added the following:

```
.ms-dialog .ms-backgroundImage #aspnetForm #ms-designer-ribbon {
    background-color: white;
}
```

So far they are working well for me.